# how see inside object tensor in spyder?

Tags: object, ide, spyder, pytorch

I am struggling to see inside an object in a spyder. when I run this snippet, in variable explorer I can see only the attached fig, however, I need to see the probs and other object tensor and also I need to access to the value of probs? any comment would appreciate.

```
import torch
from U_Net_demo import device
from dataset import test_loader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy

criterion = nn.NLLLoss()


def test():

model_load = torch.load('model.pth')

#test model
model_load.eval()
total = 0
test_loss = 0
correct = 0
count = 0
#iterate through test dataset
for ii, data in enumerate(test_loader):

            t_image, mask = data
            t_image, mask = t_image.to(device), mask.to(device)
            with torch.no_grad():

                outputs = model_load(t_image)
                #print(outputs.shape) # torch.Size([1, 2, 240, 320])
                test_loss += criterion(outputs, mask).item() / len(test_loader)

                probs = torch.exp(outputs) 

                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)  

                total += mask.nelement()
                correct += predicted.eq(mask.data).sum().item()
                accuracy = 100 * correct / total

                count +=1                
                print(count, "Test Loss: {:.3f}".format(test_loss), "Test Accuracy: %d %%" % (accuracy))


if __name__=='__main__':
    test = test()
```

[image: varaible explorer]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Pytorch tensors are not supported in Spyder's Variable Explorer as of 2019/01.

Comment: any plan to support it?

Comment: Probably after we release Spyder 4.1 in the second semester of 2019, but we can't tell for sure.